# Whats the fastest way of removing multiple empty lines?

Tags: c#, replace

I am getting a string message through an event and I am putting it in a TextBox.
Unfortunatelly, this message has many empty lines. How do I replace two empty lines with one?

My first thought is for something like this:

```
string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
textbox.text = msg.Replace(newLine + newLine, newLine);
```

I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: I would be concerned that the string doesn't necessarily have Environment.NewLine as its new line. Because of that, I'd go with @Moo-Juice's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But your `String.Replace` solution won't work if there are three newlines in a row. For example, consider:

```
string s = "hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nworld";
string s1 = s.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, "\\n{2,}", "\n");
```

`s1` will have multiple `\n` characters in it. `s2` will have only one.

This is using `\n` as an example, but the same thing applies if you're using `Environment.NewLine` (i.e. `\r\n`).

Answer (score 5):

You could use `RegEx.Replace`.

In fact, the MSDN article on that function shows how to get rid of too much white space, is very close to what you want to do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

For your purposes though, instead of looking for whitespace:

```
"\\s+";
```

You want to look for newlines:

```
"\\n+";
```

Comment: Or `@"\n+"` so escaping is not a concern.

Comment: Nice, but regex is really slow though

Comment: @odyodyodys, if there is a *noticeable and unacceptable* slowdown of your program and it was shown to be this *single* routine, than I would advocate a different method.  One should not always thing in terms of speed until it is actually an issue. :)

Answer (score 5):

How about leveraging `string.Split()` with the option `RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, message.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

This would also cover more than two newlines in a row as opposed to just two.

Answer (score 2):

`textbox.text = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(" + Environment.NewLine + ")+", Environment.NewLine);` should do the trick

Comment: You should use Environment.NewLine as this is not new line for every system. It can be (as in my situation)  `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, but then you have two problems. Your code is simpler--use String.Replace.

Comment: I like the Zawinski reference there :)

Comment: I'm no huge fan of regular expressions, but they do have their place. This is one of them. There is no way to tell `StringReplace` "turn two or more newlines into a single newline."

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  I wanted to get the answer in quick and move on to get some work done, but the original suggestion would only replace 2-for-1, not n-for-1.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes two things.

1) The newline character you are trying to replace is the Windows newline character and say the Unix newline character.

2) That you only want to replaces instances where "newline + newline" happen and not "newline + newline + newline" which would then as is be "newline + newline".  Remember String.Replace creates a new string.

In other words your idea is flawed.

I suggest reading this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-whitespace